# Attach an image to an email coming from an html page?

Tags: html

I have a photo-gallery type html page. I am able to send emails using the `<a href mailto:>` function when a certain picture is selected. I would like to have that picture be automatically included in the email whether as an attachment (preferably) or in the body.

Comment: How are you sending the emails?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.

The `mailto:` URI scheme provides no mechanism to either attach files or provide HTML formatted email.

The closest you could come would be to specify the URL *as plain text* in the body of the email (using `body=` in the query string).

Alternatively, send the email using server side code (which would give you full control over its content).